# Deep understanding on exponential generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In spite of having done some exercises, I still find it harder to understand exponential generating function deeply than ordinary generating function. Could someone explain it "deeply"? Or are there any articles on that?

Comment: I suggest that you either read the book by Bergeron, Labelle and Leroux or that you ask a more precise question. The book might help to convince you that egfs are simpler than ogfs.

http://books.google.com/books?id=83odtWY4eogC&printsec=frontcover&dq=labelle+species&hl=de&ei=Cc61TuDANsqWhQfGxOGaBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Hmm. The Wikipedia page on [symbolic combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_combinatorics) might be helpful, though I suppose you could say it's terse. No doubt user Qiaochu has some posts laying around somewhere or other on this topic.

Comment: I like "Generatingfunctionology" by Wilf. The 2nd edition can be downloaded from http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html. The 3rd edition is available from the publisher.

Comment: Chapter $3$ of Miklós Bóna’s *Introduction to Enumerative Combinatorics* gives a nice introductory sense of the respective contexts in which egf’s and ogf’s are useful.

Comment: Think of it this way: there are situations where the EGF is simple/easy to manipulate when the OGF is unwieldy or has no closed form, and vice-versa...

Comment: anon guessed correctly, [here's](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/10601) an old blog post by Qiaochu somewhat related to this.

Answer (score 2):

We typically use ordinary generating functions when counting *unlabelled objects* and exponentially generating functions when counting *labelled objects*. For instance combinatorial enumeration of *permutations* is most convenient analysed by *exponential generating functions*.

Here  I'd like  to give an indication which structures do we count when applying the *binomial convolution* 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}b_kc_{n-k}
\end{align*}
of two exponential  generating functions  $B(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j  \frac{z^j}{j!}$     and    $C(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty    c_k\frac{z^k}{k!}$.

> **Permutations:**
>   We  introduce  a *universe* $\mathcal{P}$ of (labelled) permutations. We label the *atoms* of the permutations of size $n$ as usual with $1,2,\ldots,n$. We also add an *empty* permutation $\varepsilon$ of length $0$ and consider
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{P}=\{\varepsilon,1,12,21,123,132,213,231,312,321,\ldots\}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The coefficients $a_n$ of the corresponding *exponential* generating function $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{z^n}{n!}$ give the number $n!$ of permutations of size $n$. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!\frac{z^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-z}}
> \end{align*}
>
> - We observe that generating functions like $\frac{1}{1-z}$ may serve as *both*, ordinary generating functions 
>     \begin{align*}
>   \frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\color{blue}{1}+\color{blue}{1}\cdot z+\color{blue}{1}\cdot     z^2+\color{blue}{1}\cdot   z^3+\cdots
>   \end{align*}
>     to count for instance a *sequence of unary words*
>     \begin{align*}
>   \mathcal{S}=\{\varepsilon,\bullet,\bullet\bullet,\bullet\bullet\bullet,\ldots\}\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}
> - as well as exponential generating functions
>     \begin{align*}
>   \frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!\frac{z^n}{n!}=\color{blue}{0!}+\color{blue}{1!}\cdot \frac{z}{1!}+\color{blue}{2!}\cdot  \frac{z^2}{2!}+\color{blue}{3!}\cdot \frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots
>   \end{align*}
>     to count permutations according to (1).
> - Note, the simplicity of the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\cdots$ strongly indicates the universe of permutations is *the* prototypical structure approachable by exponential generating functions.

**Warmup:** Multiplicative structure of ordinary generating functions.

We consider $\mathcal{B}=\{\bullet,\bullet\bullet\bullet\},\mathcal{C}=\{\bullet,\bullet\bullet\}$ with corresponding generating functions $B(z)=z+z^3, C(z)=z+z^2$ and obtain due to the multiplicative rule
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\mathrm{card}\left(\mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{C}\right)=\mathrm{card}\left(\mathcal{B}\right)\cdot \mathrm{card}\left(\mathcal{C}\right)}
\end{align*}
the set $\mathcal{A}=\{(\bullet,\bullet),(\bullet,\bullet\bullet),(\bullet\bullet\bullet,\bullet),(\bullet\bullet\bullet,\bullet\bullet)\}$ and the following relationship
\begin{align*}
A(z)&=\sum_{a\in\mathcal{A}}z^{|a|}=\sum_{(\beta,\gamma)\in(\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{C})}z^{|\beta|+|\gamma|}
=\left(\sum_{\beta\in \mathcal{B}}z^{|\beta|}\right)\times\left(\sum_{\gamma\in \mathcal{C}}z^{|C|}\right)=B(z)\cdot C(z)\\
A(z)&=z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5\\
&=z^{1+1}+z^{1+2}+z^{3+1}+z^{3+2}=\left(z^1+z^3\right)\times\left(z^1+z^2\right)=(z+z^3)(z+z^2)
\end{align*}
which follows from distributing products over sums.

> **Multiplicative structure of exponential generating functions:**
>
> In order to cover the *binomial convolution* $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}b_kc_{n-k}$  of exponential generating functions we will encounter a more sophisticated multiplicative rule for *labelled* structures. Nevertheless we will do  it  similarly  to the  warmup above.
>
> We consider $\mathcal{B}=\{123,213\},\mathcal{C}=\{12\}$ with generating functions $B(z)=2\frac{z^3}{3!}, C(z)=\frac{z^2}{2!}$  and  consider  the   multiplicative rule
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathcal{B}\star\mathcal{C}=\bigcup_{\beta\in\mathcal{B},\gamma\in\mathcal{C}}\left(\beta\star\gamma\right)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   which   is defined    as:
>
> - The labelled  product (3) of $\mathcal{B}$  and $\mathcal{C}$,  denoted  $\mathcal{B}\star\mathcal{C}$, is  obtained by forming ordered pairs from  $B\star C$ and performing **all possible  order-consistent relabellings**.

The last phrase  *all  possible order-consistent relabellings* needs to be explained. 
With the  example $\mathcal{B}=\{123,213\}$ and $\mathcal{C}=\{12\}$ we perform a relabeling.

At first we start with a relabelling and select wlog $\mathcal{C}=\{45\}$ by respecting the order ($1<2$, i.e. $4<5$). We now obtain all *order-consistent relabellings* as follows
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{B}\star\mathcal{C}&=\bigcup_{\beta\in\mathcal{B},\gamma\in\mathcal{C}}\left(\beta\star\gamma\right)\\
&=\left(\{123\}\star\{45\}\right)\cup\left(\{213\}\star\{45\}\right)\\
&=\{12345,12435,12534,13425,13524,14523,23415,23514,24513,34512\}\tag{4}\\
&\qquad\cup\{21345,21435,21534,31425,31524,41523,32415,32514,42513,43512\}\tag{5}\\
\end{align*}

When looking at the  set $\{123\}\star\{45\}$ we can find all order-consistent relabelings as follows: We have to generate permutations of length $5$. We create all $\binom{5}{3}=10$ strings of length $3$ from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ which follow the order $1<2<3$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\{123,124,125,134,135,145,234,235,245,345\}.
\end{align*}
Note, that each element in the set above follows the ordering $(\mathrm{smallest} < \mathrm{middle} < \mathrm {largest})$. We complete (4) by concatenating each $3$-element string with a string consisting of the remaining two elements from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ following the order $4<5$, i.e. $(\mathrm{smallest} < \mathrm{largest})$. Similarly we build (5) by respecting the order $2<1<3$, i.e. $(\mathrm{middle} < \mathrm{smallest} < \mathrm{largest})$.

> We observe from (4), (5):
>
> \begin{align*}
> |\mathcal{B}\star\mathcal{C}|=2\binom{5}{3}=2\cdot 10=20
> \end{align*}
>
> and the relationship with the generating functions $B(z)$ and $C(z)$ is given as
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(z)}&=B(z)\cdot C(z)=\left(2\cdot \frac{z^3}{3!}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{z^2}{2!}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2\binom{5}{3}\frac{z^5}{5!}}
> \end{align*}

**Hint:** This answer is based upon the great presentation of admissible structures in chapter 1 and 2 of *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.